# js solution to... Commentor can only post one comment BUT can reply to their comment tree unlimited

Tags: comments, javascript

This question is very similar but not exactly the same as this.. [One comment per user per post but be able to reply to existing comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162419/one-comment-per-user-per-post-but-be-able-to-reply-to-existing-comments)

I'd like a js solution so it doesn't need to modify any of my theme files.

I'd like a commentor to be able post 1 comment only and then only be able to reply to that comment they posted.

Comment: If you would like a JS solution then the answer is that it is impossible

Comment: Just write a custom plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just with JS there is no way, because the visitor can reload the page or close window and reopen and reset everything.

You can create a table in your wordpress database where the user's name will be saved with 0 (if no comments was done) and the id of the post (if commented). So in one more column, you create the replies number, starting with 0 and go increasing up to 3.

With JS you can access the database via AJAX requisitions, and add one more count of replies and when it's 3, return a negative message.

This is the "JS way" that I see.

I Hope to help you.

Comment: there is no need for additional table, should be very easy to use the comments api to query the comments for the required conditions